# Is there a way to count the number of occurrences of a category and assign a value in Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, countif

Suppose there's a table with the following characteristics:

```
Subject    Topic     Issue  Subject RAG Rating
Biology    Cells     Y      
Biology    Mitosis   Y      
Maths      Algebra   N      
Computing  Python    N      
Computing  R         Y
```

Where `Subject RAG Rating` is a blank column. I want to populate this column with either `R` if the subject has two or more issues; `A` if the subject has 1 issue; or `G` if the subject has no issues.

Is there a formula that can do this and return a value for each row that looks like:

```
Subject    Topic     Issue  Subject RAG Rating
Biology    Cells     Y      R
Biology    Mitosis   Y      R
Maths      Algebra   N      G
Computing  Python    N      A
Computing  R         Y      A
```

I thought that perhaps `COUNTIF` might work, i.e. count the number of `Y` or `N`, but I'm unsure how you can tell Excel to populate the rows with `R`, `A` or `G`. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm not behind a pc to test this but what about `=MID("GAR",MAX(2,COUNTIFS(A$2:A$6,A2,B$2:B$6,"Y"))+1,1)`. You could also use `CHOOSE()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of Excel, you can do this in several ways.

I strongly suggest that you turn your data into an Excel Table object with Ctrl-T or Insert > Table. That has benefits for writing formulas and addressing cells.

If you have an Office 365 subscription, you can use the LET() function to avoid duplicating parts of the formula:

```
=LET(CountResult,COUNTIFS([Subject],[@Subject],[Issue],"y"),IF(CountResult>1,"R",IF(CountResult=1,"A","G")))
```

If you don't have the LET() function, go the conventional way:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS([Subject],[@Subject],[Issue],"y")>1,"R",IF(COUNTIFS([Subject],[@Subject],[Issue],"y")=1,"A","G"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another one:

```
=LOOKUP(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,"Y"),{0,1,2},{"G","A","R"})
```

[image]